# How to describe the given relation on A using set builder notation?

Tags: relations

```
A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

S = { (0, 4), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0) }
```

S is a relation on set A.
How do we describe this relation?

Is the following description correct?

```
S = {(x,y): x ∈ A, y ∈ A, x + y is even}
```

And can we write `x,y ∈ A` at once or we have to write `x ∈ A, y ∈ A` ?

Does the relation have to contain all the even sums to be described in above way ?

Comment: No. Consider $(0, 2)$ or $(4, 2)$

Comment: To address your third question, you can write $(x,y)\in A^2$.

Comment: Yes, you can write $x,y\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct, otherwise $(2,4) \in S$.

Guide:

Notice that $0+4=1+3 = \ldots = 4+0$.

Comment: I can only observe a pattern that x is increasing from 0 to 4 and y decreasing from 4 to 0. But not able to describe it.

Comment: they always sum to a number, $0+4=4$, $1+3=4$, $\ldots$.

Comment: oops, thank you